# Only query field if value has been passed from API in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, mule, mongodb-query, anypoint-studio

I have created an API in Mule and have a number of queryParameters specified in the RAML file that I would like to use to query my store MongoDB collection.

A snippet of the collection looks like this:

```
{
    "stores": [{
        "storeId": 1234,
        "storeName": "Shop Around Ltd",
        "opens": "09:00:00.000Z",
        "closes": "17:00:00.000Z",
        "departments": ["clothing", "computers", "toys", "kitchen and home"],
        "address": {
            "street": "street1",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "New York",
            "zipCode": "10002"
        }
    }]
}
```

My problem is that the query parameters used to query the collection may be different each time so how can I write a dynamic query for MongoDB so it only queries on the fields that have been passed in with values instead of writing a query for each combination of query parameters?  E.g. I may want to query based on zip code for one query so all the other fields will be blank and the next time I may want to query on the departments and whether the store will be open at 11am.

The query will be called from Mule.

Thanks

Comment: You need to create your dynamic query at your application level.

Comment: if it was in java i would say create a map<field, condition> say if you want to get all students in class x with percentage great than 75%, in the map i would put <"class","X"> and <"percentage":"{$gt : 75}"> and i would use  this map to construct my query. not sure if this is a good idea. just thought of it. I believe you case use the java component in mule to do something similar.